# Running code in loop inside gazebo-ros plugin

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Any time I have used gazebo-ros plugin of any type, I would always define an update function that is called on every world update and but the code I need to run there.

```
this->updateConnection = event::Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin(
                                boost::bind(&MyPlugin::onUpdate, this));
```

But now I need the code to be run even if the simulation is paused. What can I use to achieve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23032/running-code-in-loop-inside-gazebo-ros-plugin/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2019-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo doesn't offer any periodic callbacks on the server which work on paused mode. But you should be able to implement your own by spinning a new thread which has a while loop. Just be careful not to call any physics functions from that thread, especially non-const functions.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0